# Converting russian string to datetime

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, encoding, lxml, non-latin

I am trying to scrape a russian website. However i am stuck with trying to convert a russian cyrillic to DateTime object.

Let's take this html piece for example:

```
<div class="medium-events-list_datetime">22 января весь день</div>
```

I am able fetch the content of this div by using lxml, i.e:

```
date = root.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/text()')[0].strip()
```

So the relevant part of of this string is 22 января, which is day and a month.

To get this part i am using the `.split()` method

Now here lies the problem, i am trying to convert this into DateTime.
I try to use DateParser: https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
,which is supposed to support russian.

However it returns `None` when i pass this string to `dateparser.parse()`

Did anyone run into similar issue? I am banging my head against the wall on this one. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

try running this example:

```
#coding=utf-8
import dateparser
s = u"22 января"
print dateparser.parse(s)
```

It should output `2016-01-22 00:00:00`

Important: Make sure that you're actually using **utf-8** strings. More info: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Otherwise your parsing/splitting might be wrong, so try having a look at the results after the `split()`.

Comment: The thing is that i want to pass to dateparser.parse() whatever returns me from date = root.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/text()')[0].strip() - it returns unicode, after .split() it is also unicode, however the dateparser still returns None. When i declare the unicode literal and pass it to dateparser it works though.

Comment: Maybe you can add some more of your code to your post above to show how you pass the results of `split()` to the `dateparser`. Maybe also add some intermediate prints to display your values. 
Note that for example `split()` returns a list of strings and not just a string.